# change the values of list in c# based on the certain value

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, reflection

I have the below mentioned list  **`result`**  which contains the volume for Eastern Day Light time  and i want have `latestResult` list  volume data for Mountain Standard Time

Can anyone please suggest optimized code to update the list values

```
var result = new List<XYZ>();
var latestResult = new List<XYZ>();

for(j=1;j<latestResult.count;j++)
for (i= diffvol;i< result.count; i++)
{
   //Code to implement

}
}

  public class XYZ
{
  public Decimal? B1Volume { get; set; }
  public Decimal? B2Volume { get; set; }
  public Decimal? B3Volume { get; set; }
public Decimal? B4Volume { get; set; }
  public Decimal? B5Volume { get; set; }
  .............
  .............
 public Decimal? B24Volume { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to assign the value based on the timezone difference, Let's assume the timezone difference is 3 hours, I am assigning diffvol variable to 3 in the code

If the diffvol is 3 in the first iteration the following values need to be assigned to the list items

```
latestResult[0].B1Volume =  result[0].B3Volume;
latestResult[0].B2Volume =  result[0].B4Volume; 
latestResult[0].B3Volume = result[0].B5Volume;
...............
.................
latestResult[0].B21Volume = result[0].B24Volume;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please show some input/output example data

Comment: @GiladGreen I am trying the shift the volume based on timezone, Let's say the result list contains volume for Pacific Daylight Time , I want to show the volumes in Central Daylight time , Based on the timezone difference i will assign the volume to new list

Comment: B3Volume,B4Volume and B5Volume are not defined in the XYZ class... that shouldn't even compile. Don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but it seems you want to 'shift' those Decimal values. In that case, instead of defining them like that, I'd define a List, so then you can shift based on your index (something like  `latestResult[0][n] = result[0][n+diffvol`). Anyway... more info is needed

Comment: @DIe let me edit the question

Comment: Everything should be much easier if you have an array of (24) `decimal?` or maybe a (`List<decimal> `); then you can work on indexes (i.e, BSomeNumberVolume become `bVolume[SomeNumber]`. with the latter, you can use index, with the first, you are forced to work with every field (unless you go with reflection, but that's not the way to go IMHO). Note that if you don't/cant break client code, you can just map the current 24 autogenerated properties to corresponding properties that read/write the elements of the array

Comment: @GianPaolo thanks for the reply .....what if my list contains properties with other data types ?